# Define color of line drawn with Python Imaging Library from an RGB tuple?

Tags: python, draw, imaging

I am trying to simply draw a vertical line and define the color based on an RGB tuple.  ex. (100, 200, 80).  I do not see anything in the Python Imaging Library that will allow me to define the color based on the tuple.  Is there something I am missing in the library, or another library, that will allow me to define the color base on the RGB values?

I have already tried using

```
finalImage = Image.new("RGB", (1000, 20000))
finalImageDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(finalImage)
finalImageDraw.line([(i, 0), (i, 1000)], fill=avgColor)
```

Where avgColor is a tuple. ie. (100, 75, 110).  But it only draws black lines. Is this the correct usage?

Comment: What mode is your image?

Comment: I added the declaration of the ImageDraw to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `fill` argument on the [draw.line](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.line) method.

You can use RGB, HSV or even named colours.

Example (from the documentation)

```
import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("lena.pgm")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# Fill=128 creates a grey line
draw.line((0, 0) + im.size, fill=128)   
draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill=128)
del draw

# write to stdout
im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")
```

Comment: This would be the correct usage, right?          finalImageDraw.line([(i, 0), (i, 1000)], fill=avgColor)      Where avgColor is a tuple (ie. (100, 98,110)?   I tried this and all of the lines it draws are black.

Comment: check what type of image - i had a similar issue when i first started using PIL - and it was because i was creating a monochrome image.

Comment: have a look at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode - as to what values to use when creating images.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Is was actually an issue with the positions where I define where to draw the line.  They actually were drawing the lines but they were just really tiny in the corner of the image that you could only see if you zoomed really far in.  I adjusted the indexes and it now works as expected.

Comment: @JacobMalachowski - can you accept the answer then if it solved your problem - thanks.